# Is this variable being safely accessed by using synchronization?

Tags: java, nested, synchronized

I have a case in which a Java class has a superclass that contains a synchronized block.

```
Class SuperClassA {
     private Bitmap bmpA;

     protected abstract Bitmap createBitmap();

     public void run() {
          synchronized (this) {
               bmpA = createBitmap();
          }
     }

     // some other codes.
}

Class SubClassB extends SuperClassA {
     private Bitmap outBmpB;

     protected Bitmap createBitmap() {
          outBmpB = ..... // create and process "outBmpB".

          Bitmap bmp;
          bmp = ..... // create and process "bmp".
          return bmp;
     }

     public Bitmap getOutBmpB() {
          Bitmap tempBmp;
          synchronized (this) {
               tempBmp = outBmpB.clone();
          }
          return tempBmp;
     }

     // some other codes.
}
```

The "getOutBmpB()" method in Class B is run by a thread while the inherited "run()" method in ClassB is run by another thread. The "createBitmap()" method implemented in ClassB should be run in a synchronized block inside the "run()" method.

My question is that I am not sure whether the newly defined class variable "outBmpB" in ClassB is safely accessed by the two threads. I am not sure the "synchronized (this)" block in the "run()" method would also "lock" the "outBmpB" variable defined just in ClassB ? If not, then could I add a "synchronized (this)" block in the "createBitmap()" implementation. e.g.

```
 protected Bitmap createBitmap() {
      synchronized (this) {
           outBmpB = ..... // create and process "outBmpB".
      }

      Bitmap bmp;
      bmp = ..... // create and process "bmp".
      return bmp;
 }
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Lawrence

Comment: Are `createBitmapA()` and `createBitmap()` the same method with a typo?

Comment: That code was hard to follow. The synchronisation is done because of the assignment to outBmpB. Nested synchronisation is no problem. The fact you override createBitmap, and in one version do not synchronize there is maybe a style issue, but all looks like it might work.

Comment: @JoopEggen so does he or does he not override `createBitmap()`? :)

Comment: @alf: (First the abstract declaration has a typo: createBitmap**A**.) The answer is: one can write in the subclass `@Overriden`, so it is overriden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *have to* synchronize it since it is already synchronized in super class and there are no other calls, but you should. Your implementation of `createBitmap()` relies on implementation details from the super class.
Do synchronization at every point you access your shared fields.

Due to this facts your current subclass' code is very error-prone!

While it is questionable to ever synchronize over `this`, it is a much better idea to synchronize over a private object nobody else can access. So your code cannot be broken by clients using your class objects and synchronize on it.

Comment: I wouldn't be so harsh on the `this` part; it could be a problem indeed, in public API—but almost only in APIs. +1 for mentioning that the approach is error-prone :)

Comment: I'm sorry when it sounded harsh, it should not. It should be a hint for being defensive and aware of side-effects it can have to synchronize over `this`. (i.e. Microsoft warns about synchronizing over `this` in C# and recommends to never do it. And in my opinion they're right at this point.)

Comment: @Erick Robertson Maybe this states it more clear: "You must synchronize and it is done in super class method which is the only one calling `createBitmap()`. But when call-hierarchie or super class implementation changes it may break synchronization. So subclass method should do proper synchronization on its own."

Comment: @ErickRobertson is it better now? I'd also change the *properly* to something, err, less encouraging, but that would be too much of a change.

Comment: I think the most confusing part is the "this" reference in the "run()" method. I feel hard to know whether it refers to a ClassA object or a ClassB object. As ClassA is a base class that I do not want to modify, I could only stick to this confusing code style in ClassA. If adding a "synchronized (this)" block in the "createBitmap()" implementation in ClassB doesn't hurt, then I would just add it there to ensure thread safety.

Comment: @user1129812 glad you understand that. I bet MS and Fabian are concerned about a different part: `this` is generally available everywhere. That is, everyone who can get hold of the object, can get lock on `this` writing `synchronized (thisVeryObject)`. That means the external code can affect the locking you perform. It is *extremely* important for APIs: if you lock on something, you'd better hide it. It's less of importance in your own code, as there's a small chance that anyone will synchronize on an instance of your object (who cares, after all?).

Answer (score 1):

It's not about "locking" a variable: you just cannot do it. You do have a proper lock in your code. However, "thread safety" means, "It's safe for any reasonable usage". As your method changing `outBmpB` is `protected`—that is, available to the package members and all the children,—you're better off explicitly synchronizing.

As a general rule, every time you access shared mutable state, you must be sure you hold the lock. In your case, you are not sure. At the same time, Java locks are reentrant, so nested synchronization will not hurt—and will perhaps save you from surprises.

Comment: Nested synchronization on the same object cannot ever hurt, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Viruzzo it can actually, if you add one more object: lock ordering is harder when you have nested locks spread by the code. Even if it's the same object. _Especially_ if it's the same object.

Answer (score -1):

As a general idea, it's better to lock on the object you are using (`bmpA` and `outBmpB` in your case) than on the container object, unless you really need to do that (and in that case a synchronized method would be better).

As per your particular case, the `synchronized (this)` blocks will exclude each other and so yes, it would work *if you don't call `createBitmap()` anywhere else*, and so it's far better to synchronize inside `createBitmap()` than inside `run()`.

Comment: Since we change the reference, locking on it does not make much sense.

Comment: @alf that was a generalized consideration; in this particular case `outBmpB` is never modified after assignment, so he wouldn't even need synchronization to begin with.

Comment: It is a misleading general consideration, which is usually wrong and harmful. Given that OP is clearly a novice, teaching bad practice doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: @alf how is it a worst practice per se than blindly synchronizing on this? Locking on the specific object, assuming you are going to modify it, seems completely reasonable. As per the changing of reference, you just need to be careful to assign to the class member as the last operation of the synchronized block.

Comment: well, let's start from the end: *you just need to be careful to assign to the class member as the last operation of the `synchronized` block* is plainly wrong.